# Format Text Going Into A Textbox for a Phone Number, etc

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, formatting, textbox, string-formatting

Couldn't find this anywhere, maybe I'm looking for the wrong verbs.

I'm trying to get a textbox to require a certain format as you type in a number. For simplicity, lets use a phone number example. As I type into the box I want some guidelines to help the user enter the correct format of the phone number:

```
(4__) ___-____

(403) 3__-____

(403) 329-98__

(403) 329-9824
```

This will prevent users from forgetting the area code, etc. I've seen this done elsewhere but am unsure of where to start.

I'm sure this is javascript but it's for a ruby on rails app so if you know of a plugin or something.

Thanks!

Josh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [masked input](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/maskedinput) jQuery plugin

Comment: Anyway to get this to work with Prototype so I don't have to include the jQuery library?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create three text inputs, and use javascript to move focus between them as they are filled?

For an example, see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2c3c/1/). It uses a quick, vanilla-JS function to advance between the inputs:

```
function advance_phone(event, next_element)
{
   var evt = event ? event : window.event; // Older versions of IE don't pass along an event object
   var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement; // Get the target of the event

   if (target.value.length == target.maxLength)
   {
     document.getElementById(next_element).focus();
   }
}
```

You take this further and enhance it to allow moving backwards between boxes when backspace is pressed and add a keypress handler to restrict allowed keys to numbers. Or you could even style the inputs so that it [looks like a phone field](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2c3c/2/).

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Amit's suggestion.

However, since you're using Rails you might want something dependent on Prototype instead of jQuery. Check this out http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/11/02/how-to-create-input-masks-in-html/